# Playing incoming audio data

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

I have videochat application in which I have to play incoming audio data.I have decoded the audio data but I don't know how to play the audio data. Here continuous audio data is coming so I cannot use AVAudioPlayer. When googled, many people have suggested to use AudioQueues and AudioUnit which is quite tedious to implement.
Can someone suggest a better solution?

Comment: AudioQueues are tedious to implement.

Comment: So can you suggest something?

Comment: added something, but there's better. i'll try to dig it out

Comment: I'm the author of StreamingKit... for any real time work like video chat applications you definitely want to use AudioUnits rather than AudioQueues. AudioQueues are quite limiting and also have an inbuilt buffer delay of around 300ms which you can't get around.

Comment: Since you working in this genre I want you ask you are aware about any  method by which I can play speex sudio stream? I have been trying to configure ffmpeg ** --enable-libspeex ** . But there's always an error of libspeex not found. I have tried to compile speex package poperly too.

Comment: @tumtumtum Can you please provide a good example of playing PCM data using Audio Units? and Can we play continuos incoming PCM data using StreamingKit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Cocoa with Love article](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html?m=1) started it all but is now quite old.

I cannot find the library I was thinking of, although it may have been closed source. Looking around I found [StreamingKit](https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit) which looks really great! If I ever have to update my own streaming code (trust me, you don't want it), I'd probably replace it with something like this.

Comment: Yes, please do comment with a new solution. I don't want to store the audio data to any file. I want to play as it comes.

Comment: Oops, I got the name wrong. What was I thinking? TantrumKit is a pretty cool name though.